# giving parameters into math function

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32f4discovery

If I call in C, math function `"trunc" in math library is define as:

```
extern double trunc _PARAMS((double));
```

and in my main file call it:

```
int i = (int)trunc(2.5);
```

It works fine, no problems. But if I try to pass double passively, like:

```
double d = 2.5;
int i = (int)trunc(d);
```

It won't work?!? In my microprocessor STM32F4 IDE it goes in debugger mode into:

```
 Infinite_Loop:
 b  Infinite_Loop
```

and it stuck there. I also change double and try float, int, unit8_t,... no one isn't working.
Also other math functions will work fine as I call them like this:

```
i =  sin(1);
i =  cos(1);
```

But, it will crashed the same, if called like this:

```
int a = 1;
i = sin(a);
i = cos(a);
```

I am running this code on microprocessor STM32F4 Discovery,IDE is Eclipse Ac6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer the man page for [`trunc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/trunc) you should note that, it says

> Link with -lm

So, make sure that you are linking with `-lm`.

Secondly, when synopsis say `double trunc(double x);`, there is no point in trying it out with other data types.

If you want to try with other data types then you should look for these variants:

```
float truncf(float x);
long double truncl(long double x);
```

Test code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>     

int main(void)
{
    // using trunc function which return
    // Truncated value of the input 
    double d = 2.7;
    printf(" Truncated value is %d \n", (int)trunc(d)); 

    return 0;
}
```

This generated an output:

```
 Truncated value is 2
```

And it was compiled with gcc version 5.3.0

When I compile the same code gcc version 7.2.0 without `-lm` option,
I get following warning:

```
undefined reference to `trunc'
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```